# How to update in laravel with related id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have on table `assets` and I want to update each `code` column as `'ASSET000'`+ `primary id` of table like below

```
Asset0001 for id 1
Asset0002 for id 2
Asset0003 for id 3
```

In mysql query will be

```
UPDATE assets SET code = concat('ASSET000', id)
```

How can I write in Laravel

```
DB::table('assets')->update('code',????)
```

Comment: is it ok to use `DB::raw()` ?

Comment: you mean `DB::raw("concat('ASSET000', id)")` ?

Comment: Yes like that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DB::raw()` you can do it like this :

```
DB::table('assets')->update(['code' => DB::raw( CONCAT('ASSET000', id) )])
```

Comment: Happy to help :)